# Servicio PostgreSQL no disponible

Tags: postgresql, windows, localhost, pgadmin, tcpip

recién instalé la versión de pgAdmin 4 v6 en mi pc, lo curioso fue que cuando intente conectar al servidor no me lo permite, obtengo un error:

> Connection to server "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed:
> Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that
> host and accepting TCP/IP Connections? Connection to server at
> "localhost"(::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
> (0x0000274D/10061) Is the server running on that host and accepting
> TCP/IP Connections?

[image: Error generado]

Verifiqué los servicios de Windows pero el servicio PostgreSQL no aparece entre el listado.
[image: No aparece el servicio PostgreSQL en los servicios de Windows]

Intenté:

- Reinstalando pgAdmin y borrar todos los archivos generados por la instalación
- Agregué una regla de excepción en el firewall de Windows para pgAdmin
- Crear un nuevo grupo de servidores en pgAdmin
  [image: Intenté agregar regla en firewall de Windows]

No consigo arrancar el servidor PostgreSQL
Alguna solución???

Comment: Parece que el problema no es de pgAdmin, sino de Postgresql. ¿Cómo lo tienes instalado?

Comment: Solución: Instale una versión anterior de PostgreSQL y de PGAdmin